a variable disappears for an unknown reason
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define I 27
#define IR 25
#define File "test.txt"

struct customer
{
    long long identity;
    char iban[I];
    int money;
};

void filesave(struct customer cus)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(File,"a");
    if (file==NULL)
    {
        printf("the file did not open properly.");
    }

    fprintf(file,"%lld %s %d \n",cus.identity,cus.iban,cus.money);

    fclose(file);
}

int identitycontrol(long long identity)
{
     int a=0,bas;
    long long i=1;
    while (a<11)
    {
        bas=(identity/i)%10;
        if (bas<0 || bas>9)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        i*=10;
        a++;
    }
    if (identity / i > 0 && identity>0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int ibancontrol(char iban[I])
{
     if(!isalpha(iban[0]) || !isalpha(iban[1]))
     {
        return 0;
     }
     
    for (int i = 2; i < I; i++)
    {
        if (iban[i]<48 || iban[i]>57)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
    }
    return 1;
}

int moneycontrol(int money)
{
    if (money>0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int transfermoneycontrol(int b, int m)
{
    if(b>=m)
        return 1;
     else
        return 0;
}

int moneyorder(char account1[],char account2[],int transfermoney)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(File,"r");
    struct customer cus[100];
    char temp[100];
    int y=0,s=0;
    while ( fgets(temp,100, file) != NULL )
    {
            sscanf(temp,"%lld %s %d",&cus[s].identity,cus[s].iban,&cus[s].money);
    
        // printf("%d",strlen(cus[s].iban));
        if(strcmp(cus[s].iban,account1)==0)
        {
                cus[s].money -=transfermoney;  
                y++;

        }
        if(strcmp(cus[s].iban,account2)==0)
        {
            cus[s].money +=transfermoney;
            y++;
        }
        s++;
    }    
        printf("%s\n",account1);
        printf("%s\n",cus[0].iban);

     for(int z=0;z<s;z++)
    {
        printf("\nGuncel bilgiler:\n");
        printf("%d: %s  %lld  %d \n",z+1,cus[z].iban,cus[z].identity,cus[z].money);
    }
    
    fclose(file);

    

   
    
    file = fopen(File, "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("the file did not open properly.");
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < s; x++)
    {
       filesave(cus[x]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return  1;
}

int main()
{
    int choice=0,control=0;
    struct customer cus;
    char account1[I];
    char account2[I];
    int transfermoney;
   
    
    while (1)
    { 

    printf("-----Menü-----\n");
    printf("1:Entry\n");
    printf("2:Transfer\n");
    printf("3:Exit\n");

    printf("What is your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice); 
    fflush(stdin);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        while (1)
        {   
                printf("Please enter your identity: ");
                scanf("%lld",&cus.identity);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (identitycontrol(cus.identity)==1)
                {
                    
                break;
                }   
        }
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your iban: ");
                scanf("%s",cus.iban);
                //fgets(cus.iban,I,stdin);
                //cus.iban[strlen(cus.iban)-1]='\0';                
                fflush(stdin);
                if (ibancontrol(cus.iban)==1)
                {
                    
                    break;
                }
        }
        
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your money: ");

                scanf("%d",&cus.money);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (moneycontrol(cus.money)==1)
                {
                    break;
                }    
        }     
                filesave(cus);
        break;
        case 2 :
        while(1)
        {
                printf("Please enter the main account we will send money to: ");
                fflush(stdin);
              //  fgets(account1,I,stdin);
               // account1[strlen(account1)-1]='\0';
                scanf("%30s",account1);
              fflush(stdin);
            // getchar();
               if (ibancontrol(account1)==1)
               {
                   break;
               }
                      
        }
        while(1)
        {
                printf("Please enter the account from which you will receive money: ");
                //fgets(account2,I,stdin);  
                scanf("%30s",account2);
               fflush(stdin);
             //getchar();
                if (ibancontrol(account2)==1)
                { 
                    break;
                }  
        }        
        
       while(1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your transfer money: ");
                scanf("%d",&transfermoney);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (moneycontrol(transfermoney)==1)
                {
                   break;
                }          
        }
                
                int a=moneyorder(account1,account2,transfermoney);
            if (a==1)
            {
                printf("Money order sucsessful.\n");
            }
            else if (a==0)
            {
                printf("Money order unsucsessful.\n");
            }
            


            
            break;
        case 3:
                exit(2);
        break;
    default:
                printf("Wrong choice!!\n");
        break;
    }
   
}
 return 0;



}

After getting the account1 variable, I can print it, but when it enters the world containing account 2, account1 disappears, but I don't know why.All the remaining functions and file operations are working, but there is a problem in that part.account1 disappears, I cannot press it in a way that I do not understand or the function. When I send it, it's empty inside, just \n

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically please post a [mre].

In filesave you detect the file not opening properly, print an error message, then continue on to print into it.

"but when it enters the world containing account 2, account1 disappears" It isn't quite clear whatr you mean by that. Please describe what you see. A compiler error? An unwanted behaviour at run time?

Probably not your problem: scanf("%30s",account2); should probably be scanf(" %26s",account2); instead. A space in the format string to consume leading whitespace and a value of 26 to prevent overflow of a char[27].

Welcome to StackOverflow, while you follow the guidelines mentioned in the comment above. While I quickly have a look at your program, I notice that the issue might be related to how you're handling input and buffer flushing. The use of fflush(stdin) can cause undefined behavior, as fflush is meant for output streams. What I'd recommend is remove fflush(stdin) and replaced it with proper buffer clearing.
Additionally, you can add a function to clear the input buffer and Use fgets to read strings and remove the newline character.
Take a look at the clear_buffer function:
void clear_buffer() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

Now all you got to do is Replace fflush(stdin) with clear_buffer and adjust string input - In main(), replace occurrences of fflush(stdin) and update the string input handling
Example of one such replacement:
// In the while loop for identity input
while (1) {
    printf("Please enter your identity: ");
    scanf("%lld", &cus.identity);
    clear_buffer();
    if (identitycontrol(cus.identity)) {
        break;
    }
}

You can do the same for similar occurrences everywhere else.

I feel this should address the issue with account1 disappearing when you enter account2. Basically, just removing the improper fflush(stdin) and ensuring the input buffer is correctly handled can solve the issue
